# How do I resolve the time limit?

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, tree, time-complexity

Write a program that determines for two nodes of a tree whether the first one is a parent of another.

Input data
The first line contains the number of vertices n (1 ≤ n ≤ 10^5) in a tree. The second line contains n numbers, the i-th one gives the vertex number of direct ancestor for the vertex i. If this value is zero, then the vertex is a root of a tree.

The third line contains the number of queries m (1 ≤ m ≤ 10^5). Each of the next m lines contains two different numbers a and b (1 ≤ a, b ≤ n).

Output data
For each of the m queries print on a separate line number 1, if the vertex a is one of the parents of a vertex b, and 0 otherwise.

[image: The picture of tree]

Input example #1

6

0 1 1 2 3 3

5

4 1

1 4

3 6

2 6

6 5

Output example #1

0

1

1

0

0

[Problem](https://www.eolymp.com/en/problems/1941)

How can I fix the time limit?
I also tried with <stdio.h>(scanf();printf()).
But problem gives time limit.
**It gives time limit for input(many input things)**
My solution:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
vector<vector<int>> g;
vector<int> time_in,time_out;
int Time=0;
void dfs(int node,int parent){
    time_in[node]=++Time;
    for(int &to:g[node]){
        if(to!=parent){
                dfs(to,node);
        }
    }
    time_out[node]=++Time;// or  time_out[node]=Time;
}
bool isAnchestor(int anch,int node){
    return time_in[anch]<=time_in[node] and time_out[anch]>=time_out[node];
}
void readInt(int &n){
    char ch;
    int sign = 1;
    while(ch = getchar(), isspace(ch)){//getchar()-->getchar_unlocked()

    };
    n = 0;
    if(ch == '-')
        sign = -1;
    else n = ch - '0';
    while(ch = getchar(), isdigit(ch))
        n = (n << 3) + (n << 1) + ch - '0';
    n *= sign;
}
int main(){
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);
    //cin.tie(0);
    cout.tie(0);
    int n,start;
    readInt(n);
    time_in.resize(n+1);
    time_out.resize(n+1);
    g.resize(n+1);
    vector<int> anchestors(n+2);
    for(int i=1; i<=n; ++i){// I am thinking: the anchestors is sorted.
            readInt(anchestors[i]);
            if(anchestors[i] != 0) {


        g[anchestors[i]].push_back(i);
        g[i].push_back(anchestors[i]);
        g[anchestors[i]].push_back(i);
    }else{
    start=i;
    }
    }
    dfs(start,1);
    int q,u,v;
    readInt(q);
    while(q--){
        readInt(u),readInt(v);
        cout<<isAnchestor(u,v)<<'\n';// The anchestor of v is u. //(u,v)-->(a,b)
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Profile your code. Where is the time spent? What is the time-complexity? ..

Comment: You're using `iostream`. You do not need to write your own `readInt` function.

Comment: Don't do premature optimizations. Don't become a member of [the cargo cult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). Write good, readable, maintainable, and *working* code first of all. Then look at the requirements, and if there are any efficiency or performance requirements. If there is, and your program is not good enough, then take an optimized build to *measure* and *benchmark* and *profile* to find the top *two* bottlenecks. Fixt those with plenty of documentation and comments. Then if it's still not good enough, find the next *one single* top bottleneck.

Comment: I don't think built-in IO operations are the reason for failing the time limit. Very often with such quests you have to find the exact algorithm they have in mind or use the correct data structure that allows you to solve the problem fast enough.

Comment: If you are learning competitive programming, you'll need to learn **a lot of algorithms**.  Time Limit Exceeded (TLE) errors are from using the wrong algorithm.  The sites are looking for obscure very efficient and sometimes specialized algorithms.

Comment: @Isa: The reason you're hitting time limits is because (A) your algorithm is incorrect and producing incorrect answers, and (B) because you're using the wrong algorithm entirely.  You don't "resolve the time limit" - you use the right algorithm.

Comment: What algorithm would you recommend to use here?

Comment: For instance, (A) your code assumes there's only one tree. (B) You add every child to it's parent twice. (C) You add parents to their children for some reason. (D) You have 10^5 heap allocations. (E) Due to B and C, I'm pretty sure the `dfs` method is something like `O(N!)`

Comment: If they say all inputs are <= 10^5 there surely is no input > 10^6 ...if you seem to get such Inputs your `readInt` isn't working correctly...

Comment: The programming challenge is to see if you can figure out the right algorithm on your own. If we told you the right algorithm, that's effectively cheating in the competition.  You need to find a O(N) algorithm that does exactly 2 heap allocations.

Comment: The issue is here: `void dfs(...)` You do not need to do a search with multiple traversal options here: just go from the descendant to the parent repeatedly until you either reach the node that's supposed to be the ancestor or you reach the root node. At this time you can determine the output...

Comment: I'd suggest to search bottom up. Ie start at the child and go up your tree until you either hit the searched parent or the root

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach using a depth first search is inefficient. This in general will look at more than just the path from `b` to `a` though the "parent pointers" or to the root, if `b` is not a descendant of `a`.

Instead start the search at `b` and go to the parent node repeatedly until you find the root or `a`. This will only consider the path from `b` to the root node. You don't need to consider any alternative paths, but you always know the edge to traverse.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    constexpr int RootParent = -1;

    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::vector<int> parents;
    parents.reserve(n);
    for (int i = 0; i != n; ++i)
    {
        int v;
        std::cin >> v;
        parents.push_back(v - 1); // note: storing 0-based indices of parents here (root's parent becomes -1)
    }

    int queryCount;
    for(std::cin >> queryCount; queryCount > 0; --queryCount)
    {
        int searchedAncestor;
        int descendant;
        std::cin >> searchedAncestor >> descendant;
        
        // inputs are still 1-based, so we need to decrement here
        --searchedAncestor;
        --descendant;

        // repeatedly go to the parent node until we reach the root or the ancestor to attempt to find
        while ((searchedAncestor != descendant) && (descendant != RootParent))
        {
            descendant = parents[descendant];
        }
        std::cout << (searchedAncestor == descendant) << '\n';
    }
}
```

[Demo on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEIADMAOykAA6oCoRODB7evv6p6ZkCIWGRLDFxSbaY9o4CQgRMxAQ5Pn4BdpgOWQ1NBCUR0bEJyQqNza15HeP9oYPlw0kAlLaoXsTI7Bzm8aHI3lgA1Cbxbk5jxJisJ9gmGgCCO3sHmMenAG5dRMQ3d48PoQIhxYTFCECWfxMiSsD0OcMOaAYY0wqhSxEOgMOACVUKgCMomowgScACKHAC0XBOMP%2B93hGMEhwY1L%2B9LG6BAKFCb1u8WwTJZsPh7M5nwcJBOZ0EN0OKUJggUgrp8LllwVADpLkpiJ8IAwIfEafT%2BOiIJi8G8yRpqRjDmAwKSBYbjpZrHgIUK4VCjfT4Zj3krfcKCByuQweTKA4bWUHZfKCAp1SkvAoEAB9KJMZAAawg7wphy4BoshwA9KWmXj2IcxiRQsAGfhNgpDqgqHG1QnDghYq8IMRcQQwBwW6qiYcYmg2C3KR7lV7EiTIZ6GUCAI5eWIATw8Xml0ZXJogIrDEb5hw3293%2B5Ll%2BIO7WjJl1ud5PJd4fe4Ic/p3pjQcxJQmmQHt0HuBhm2%2BQNY0xLAFE2Bh0EMAhoKDE9kG5X5zyAjZQPAyCSDPfk4IQpCb3/X0KPpcsGWTLtCRrRxaFoQtyUzJR0FIGtUEOAB3V4wkwdBDiIQ4sGQS42EZHtLio%2BE3xwkChPwzBax%2BA9519N8SNcZClTkuEaMuFIrgIITaC3Q5gB40SCB7DtxwYDBXi/Og%2BNeS4swQET7IHPFW3ROzXkMAjAp4pgCDMlgUiBUSaEQgy%2BIQOg%2B2PK5cOUiDVO%2BO0HXiMkdMQ5ClhdAA2cxSsOCBCrIoF7UdHE8QJTslh/WM/xXWMxNU0jkMtByFRMABWCwar0oalw0rqoSXTrg1DNAvGJU5JSqxS8KytTLUdMbBBKyVVuHYa3AYI6pvhGbIUXDgVloTght4PwOC0UhUE4NxrGsbj1k2F14h4UgCE0G6VmzEAho0fROEkR7gdezheAUEBIaB56btIOBYCQFEuiWkhyEoJpgAUAkwloIQEFQXinoBqcUjoCKslJmoKapp6XrplK4mJ5gUlTPFSE5%2BhiHCVgtl4IXYgAeSW1nqbhnHkHuYhiYRwJVC6Bp8Ce8qHg0QsDbMQ54mNv4hr%2BSRCz%2BLhDkkP4Td1%2B4jcdyqHpkQQRDEdgpHd%2BQlDUOHdC4fRDGMT7LH0PAoiRyAVlQGKsiRjheFQT5iGIPA4PgFYFDWDZvdsENQmZ8nKfltHSF44gmBSTgeFu%2B7YYrt6OGwDXkDx9FVAADlK8lSst4BkGQKqCGIPdsxKiAPtdCPDlwQhCJ2IteFRrRWtIHsmCwOJwVIMGIahjgYdIdmU7VpGUeBje7o4Mwm5elvV%2BvlY04yZxJCAA)

Answer (score -3):

Just I did wrong in input process. (//fixed)

I found solution.

```
  #include<stdio.h>
    #include<vector>
    #include<algorithm>
    using namespace std;
    vector<vector<int>> g;
    vector<int> time_in,time_out;
    int Time=0;
    void dfs(int node,int parent){
        time_in[node]=++Time;
        for(int &to:g[node]){
            if(to!=parent){
                    dfs(to,node);
            }
        }
        time_out[node]=++Time;// or  time_out[node]=Time;
    }
    bool isAnchestor(int anch,int node){
        return time_in[anch]<=time_in[node] and time_out[anch]>=time_out[node];
    }
    int main(){
        int n,start;
        scanf("%d",&n);
        time_in.resize(n+1);
        time_out.resize(n+1);
        g.resize(n+1);
    int a;
        vector<int> anchestors(n+2);
       for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){//fixed
            scanf("%d", &a);//fixed
            if (!a) start = i;//fixed
            else g[a].push_back(i);//fixed
        }//fixed
        dfs(start,-1);//fixed
        int q,u,v;
        scanf("%d",&q);
        while(q--){
            scanf("%d%d",&u,&v);
            printf("%i\n",isAnchestor(u,v));// The anchestor of v is u.//(u,v)-->(a,b)
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is a code-only answer and those promote [Cargo Cult Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) rather than real understanding. This can easily be fixed by providing an explanation that summarizes what the code is doing and how it improves performance.

Comment: When you give an answer on StackOverflow, it should explain in some sort of detail what the solution involves.  Posting a "code-only" solution is not sufficient here -- leave that for the "competitive coding" websites.